# How to import from text file to asp.net GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to import data from text file to grid view  using the blew code :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"d:\\My File3.log")))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        string[] items = line.Trim().Split(' ');
        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
            // on the first line of the file
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(items);

    }
    //show it in gridview 
    this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

My file is like :

A B C

E F D C C

E D D D

D P

Then I get the following error

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table in c# application

Comment: You are creating 3 columns because that is what the first line of your file has. The next line of the file tries to add 5.

Comment: how to fix it ?

Comment: If you are the author of that code then I have faith you can figure it out. It should be trivial and I would do you a disservice by solving it. Is that your code or are you maintaining someone else's?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the loop from column count to items array length.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (System.IO.TextReader tr = File.OpenText((@"d:\\My File3.log")))
{
string line;
while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{

    string[] items = line.Trim().Split(' ');
    if (dt.Columns.Count < items.Length)
    {
        // Create the data columns for the data table based on the number of items
        // on the first line of the file
        for (int i = dt.Columns.Count; i < items.Length; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + i, typeof(string)));
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(items);

}
//show it in gridview 
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```